# array_multisort issue with multidimensonal array in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I have the following array:

```
array(10) { 
        [0]=> array(109) {  
            ["id"]=> string(4) "2632", ["_category_sortorder"] => 8, ["_sortorder" => 1] 
        },
        [1]=> array(109) {  
            ["id"]=> string(4) "2635", ["_category_sortorder"] => 5, ["_sortorder" => 2] 
        },
        ...
}
```

I want to sort it based on two criterias:

a) by `_category_sortorder` asc **(with priority)**

b) by `_sortorder` asc

I tried this:

```
foreach($resources as $k => $v) {
    $sort[$k]['_category_sortorder'] = $resources[$k]['_category_sortorder'];
    $sort[$k]['_sortorder'] = $resources[$k]['_sortorder'];
 }

array_multisort($sort['_category_sortorder'], SORT_ASC, $sort['_sortorder'], SORT_ASC, $resources);
```

But it's not working as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: try `usort()`  and define sorting behavior

Comment: Maybe try flip of arrays `array_multisort($sort['_sortorder'], SORT_ASC, $sort['_category_sortorder'], SORT_ASC, $resources);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
$sort = array(
                array("id"=>"263", "_category_sortorder"=> 8, "_sortorder" => 1),
                array( "id"=>  "145", "_category_sortorder" => 155, "_sortorder" => 2),
                array( "id"=>  "2145", "_category_sortorder" => 55, "_sortorder" => 12),
                array( "id"=>  "3145", "_category_sortorder" => 155, "_sortorder" => 10),
            );

usort($sort, function(array $a, array $b) {
    return $b['_category_sortorder'] - $a['_category_sortorder'];
});


echo '<pre>';
print_r($sort);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for `_category_sortorder`, but what about `_sortorder`? Call `usort` again?

Comment: Yes if you want to sort it with _sortorder , you need to do again .but keep in mind keep the array sorted by _category_sortorder in a temp array , else it will be lost

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a simple solution but this code block is doing is job:
You split the array in sub arrays including only elements with the same _category_sortorder value. Then you sort each sub array with usort. At the end you merge them together.

```
<?php
    $array = [
        ['id' => 1, '_category_sortorder' => 2, '_sortorder' => 1],
        ['id' => 2, '_category_sortorder' => 2, '_sortorder' => 3],
        ['id' => 3, '_category_sortorder' => 3, '_sortorder' => 19],
        ['id' => 4, '_category_sortorder' => 1, '_sortorder' => 2],
        ['id' => 5, '_category_sortorder' => 1, '_sortorder' => 1],
    ];

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (!isset($newElements[$value['_category_sortorder']]))
            $newElements[$value['_category_sortorder']] = [];
        $newElements[$value['_category_sortorder']][] = $value;
    }


    $array = [];
    foreach ($newElements as $key => $value) {
        usort($value, function($a, $b) {
            return strcmp($a["_sortorder"], $b["_sortorder"]);
        });
        $array[$key] = $value;
    }

    ksort($array);
    $new = [];
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $new = array_merge($new, $value);
    }
    echo "<pre>".print_r($new, true).'</pre>';
```